# Running node-express application on Heroku with constant PORT

Tags: heroku

currently my nodejs application listens on process.env.PORT

This PORT is randomly set by heroku everytime heroku starts the dyno.

However I now have multiple applications that are going to use this express application. I can no longer have the PORT updating itself randomly.

I tried setting the PORT in config section of HEROKU. That did not set the PORT however.